# How can I restrict libraries to attach to my custom controller only?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a custom module that creates its own page and displays some stuff. I have some CSS and JS to add, and I'm using a library. The CSS and JS are being added, but to every page on the site. Can someone tell me how to restrict them to this page only?

[The docs say](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module) "*But what matters most is that we don't decide whether to attach a library based on which page we're on (i.e. which URL or route), but based on which things are visible on the page...*" So, if that really is what matters most, then maybe I'm going about this all wrong?

*MycontrollerController.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mycontroller\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Returns responses for mycontroller routes.
 */
class MycontrollerController extends ControllerBase {
  public function content() {
    return [
      '#title' => 'My Controller',
      '#plain_text' => 'Here is some text.'
    ];
  }
}
```

*mycontroller.info.yml*

```
name: My Controller
description: It's a very nice controller
type: module
core: 8.x
```

*mycontroller.routing.yml*

```
mycontroller:
  path: '/mycontroller'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Mycontroller'
    _controller: '\Drupal\mycontroller\Controller\MycontrollerController::content'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

*mycontroller.libraries.yml*

```
mylibrary:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    layout:
      css/mycontroller-layout.css: {}
  js:
    js/mycontroller.js: {}
```

*mycontroller.module*

```
<?php
function mycontroller_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'mycontroller/mylibrary';
}
```

*My directory structure...*

```
mycontroller
|-- css
|   `-- mycontroller-layout.css
|
|-- js
|   `-- mycontroller.js
|
|-- mycontroller.info.yml
|-- mycontroller.libraries.yml
|-- mycontroller.module
|-- mycontroller.routing.yml
`-- src
    `-- Controller
        `-- MycontrollerController.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your render array can return the `#attached` property:

```
$build = [
 '#title' => 'My Controller',
 '#plain_text' => 'Here is some text.'
];

$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'mycontroller/mylibrary';

return $build;
```

See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.2.x